# Placement/order of buttons

Tags: buttons, placement

I'm designing a form that will be used for posting an advertisement. The form will include the following buttons in its bottom section:

- **Reset**
- **Preview**
- **Update**

I need advice regarding the ordering and placement of these buttons. what would be the best, most logical button arrangement for this case?

The current arrangement can be seen here:

[image: UI Sample]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it in order of **importance**, assuming the left is the least important, and the right is the most important. In most cases importance = amount of frustration if misused, and permanence. Under that logic you're order should be changed from it's current: Reset, Preview Update, to: Preview, Update, Reset, but I think in this specific case an exception should be made, and it should be Preview, Reset, Update, because I believe that Update is the primary function, and thus is the most important, and I believe that it's importance far outweighs the risk of "delete" and the order should be: Preview, Reset, Update.

*As a side note: * I think that your reset button should be red, and that your update button be green, because of their positive and negative connotations, this will greatly improve usability.

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion:

Leave "rest" button out if it is meant to clear the form-fields only. No body fills out a form to find a button which asks him to reset a form. If your propose is to reset whole add and its settings across multiple tabs (or sections) even then Reset is a process which cannot be undone and user essentially take the "undo-able risk" to rest his form.

Coming to your question

- If you had to place these three buttons together, I would suggest you to display "Reset" space space space "Preview" space "Update". Idea is to group buttons which perform related actions and keeping the irreverent buttons physically and visually apart.
- Regarding order, I would go with Reset, Preview and Update as you has suggested. Our visual scanning starts at top-left and ends at bottom-right. Also in any given list, first and last element is the easiest to spot and click. Considering importance and usage of Preview and Update buttons, I would suggest to keep them at the "most visible" place which is bottom-right.
- If you were looking to place your buttons on the top of the form (like in case of a web application) even then my suggested order would be the same. Reset ----- Preview - Update.
- Another layer of improvement would be give "Update" button more prominence by changing its color or providing an outline/border around it. If you do that, you can display these three buttons together as RESET - PREVIEW - **UPDATE**.

Answer (score 0):

1. Coming to the question - "I'm designing a form that will be used for
   **posting** an advertisement". Buttons labels are based on "**the action user want you to take**". Current scenario user want to post their
   advertising So labeling "Update" button to "Post" will be more
   perceived.
2. "Reset" button come to picture when you have large number of input
   field and user had to manually remove the text for each field when
   they input wrong.   No reset button is required in below example as
   the form is short 
   https://www.redbox.com/register?ReturnUrl=http%3a%2f%2fwww.redbox.com%2f

Order of placement will be - **Preview and Post next to each other**

Order of placement including the reset - **Set Reset button little bit away form the Preview and post button.** so user accidentally don't click it.
For more specific answer please share your design form screen.

Answer (score 0):

As the other posters have mentioned, it's [generally considered poor form to include "Reset" buttons on web forms nowadays](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/reset-and-cancel-buttons/).

If you're able to remove that button, you will be able to make the button order more logical, making the "Update" button the primary one (as an aside, that button's text should ideally be changed to "Save Changes", "Update Ad" or similar to make it clearer, since "Update" as a verb could also mean "Refresh the page", which has a very different meaning to the user).

So being the primary button you can put it leftmost under the form and position the "preview" button to the right of it as a secondary action.

Answer (score 0):

As with most answers, there's no real right or wrong way to do this, especially when we don't have detailed information about the exact context or users. However, some general guidelines do exist:

1. The order should be logical and consistent (e.g. most used to least used, least important to most important).
2. The default button that is highlighted should be logical, except in the case where the action may be destructive (i.e. cause loss of information), in which case you should prevent the user from being able to click it by accident and not make it default.
3. Naming convention should be simple and clear (Reset might be ambiguous if there were other steps involved in the process, so Clear might be better?)
4. Test and see if your assumptions match actual user expectations/behaviour!

Answer (score 0):

Reset buttons are not essentially required unless demanded explicitly.

- You can put the Update - Preview - Close (if any) buttons in the right lower area, as this is the common position for interacting with buttons.
- Please note that Windows follows the pattern Update (OK) and Cancel.